# How to change value of input type file in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this HTML code

```
<img src="../img/1.jpg" class="img">
<img src="../img/2.jpg" class="img">
<img src="../img/3.jpg" class="img">
<img src="../img/4.jpg" class="img">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="bgchange(this)" >
```

And this jquery

```
$(".img").click(function(){
                        var srcat=$(this).attr('src');
                        $("#file").attr('value',srcat);
                        alert($("#file").val());
                });
```

But it is not changing any value it stays empty.Is there anyway i can change that?

Comment: doesn't make sense trying to change a file input value

Answer (score 4):

You are not allowed to change the value of `input[type="file']` via script. This is a security mechanism. If this was possible, websites could steal any file in your hard drive. Not very cool.

Comment: But i have seen some website doing this thing.

Comment: @Murad what exactly did you see?

Comment: Well you should run away from that website.

Comment: Well that website is called "Facebook"

Comment: Facebook is not setting the value of file inputs using JavaScript.

Comment: If you click on change background and choose.How does it do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is your goal?

Comment: It shows you some pictures that it has on its servers. When you click on one, it sends a string identifying that image back to the server. No file input involved.

Comment: I have got a div with 10 images in it so when user clicks one of them i want background to change without submitting

Comment: You don't need an input for that, you can just change the `background-image` attribute of your element and set it to the `src` of the selected image.

Comment: No i use <img> there

Comment: Then you change the `src` attribute of that `img` tag. Or replace that `img` tag with a new one.

Comment: I have got this js code that works onchange.So i need value to be changed